# Transformicons - Open/close overlay content

Tags: jquery, html, css, icons

I have been playing around with [Zerodevx](https://zerodevx.github.io/zero-transformicon/) transformicon and I'm not sure how to get the contents of an overlay are displayed after toggling through the animation.

Here's the code snippet.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Import webcomponents-lite.js polyfill -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Import zero-transformicon build bundle -->
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">


</head>

<body>
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()"></zero-transformicon>
  <span style="float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#8641;open</span>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h1>"Fever" T-shirt</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There are two functions `openNav()`and `closeNav()` that opens and closes the overlay.

I've placed the call to openNav() function to open the overlay but I'm a bit stumped as how I would go about placing the closeNav() function when you click on the "Minus" animated icon.

I would like the overlay to appear upon clicking on the "+" icon and close the overlay by clicking when the icon animates on the "-" state.

The "-" icon should be contained within the overlay - similar to how the close "X" button in the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the documentation for Transformicons and couldn't find a way to detect the events for transformation start/end (maybe I was looking at an old version? what I found is listed as deprecated on Github).

Still, it seems that Transformicons adds a class (`tcon-transform`)
 when the icon is transformed to the secondary version (in this case, the minus). You could use that within `openNav()` to detect the state of the icon and execute one action or the other. Something like this (commented):

```
function openNav() {
  // if the element has the class tcon-transform (added/removed before calling this)
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    // the original icon was the plus: open the navigation
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  } else {
    // the original icon was the minus: close the navigation
    closeNav();
  }
}
```

You can see it working here:

```js
function openNav() {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("tcon-transform")) {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
  } else {
    closeNav();
  }
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Import webcomponents-lite.js polyfill -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.19/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Import zero-transformicon build bundle -->
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-transformicon/v0.1.0/build/zero-transformicon.build.html">


</head>

<body>
  <zero-transformicon icon="plus-minus" onclick="openNav()"></zero-transformicon>
  <span style="float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#8641;open</span>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h1>"Fever" T-shirt</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alvaro! This worked a treat. Your help is much appreciated.